# how to get data from another table based on condition

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

user_info:

```
user_id     user_name   address
    1        pavan      bangalore
    2        balu       chennai
    3        badra      hyd
```

item_info:

```
item_id   user_id   state
1           1         0
2           1         1
3           1         2
4           2         1
```

i have one method getTotalDetails,suppose if i login by admin  i need like this:

```
user_id     user_name  address   item_id   state
    1         pavan   bangalore    1         0
    1         pavan   bangalore    2         1
    1         pavan   bangalore    3         2
    2         balu     chennai     4         1
    3         badra     hyd       null      null
```

Can anyone help show me how to write a query to get the above data set?

Comment: your requested data set shows item_id to be 1,1,1,4,null but are you sure that you want that instead of 1,2,3,4,null?

Comment: Have you written anything?

Comment: sorry item_id are 1,2,3,4,null

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :-

```
SELECT user_id, username, address, item_id, state
FROM user_info LEFT JOIN item_info USING (user_id)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4af09/1)

Comment: but am not getting user_id 3 details...if suppose there is no states under user_id in that time ..i want to get user_id,user_name and address with  item_id & state as null

Comment: @user3318237 Look at the Demo. It gives the same output as you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: i saw demo..but i have problem because in item _info table user_id =donor_id...In that time how to modify above query...output is same like in demo

Comment: donor_id ? I can't understand your statement. Please learn SQL first